# Cannot Open GitHub on Windows 11

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I cannot open GitHub I already tried a lot of options like changing DNS and a bunch of other stuff still I cannot open GitHub on windows 11. Please help as this is a very new kind of problem for me.
When I edited DNS to 8.8.8.8 it showed me the second type of error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Look for hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. If it contains any entry related to github remove and save in admin mode. Voila.